# Ocamlrun.lib Not Found For Linking

Tags: winapi, ocaml, native

Trying to build the [OCaml Win32 API](http://ocaml-win32.sourceforge.net/) binaries for OCaml 3.11.0 on Win 7 and I consistently get a message when I try *nmake dynamic*: 'cannot open input file "ocamlrun.lib"'.  My google skills seem to be failing me--is there something I need to do to get this .lib file?  It doesn't seem to be part of the libraries which are included in the OCaml binary distribution for Windows.  Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - you need libcamlrun.lib. 
Long answer - ocaml-win32 Makefile is outdated. Here is a [patch](http://ygrek.org.ua/p/code/ocaml-win32-Makefile.diff). Among others it fixes indentation for GNU make and removes wrong precompiled headers options. Unfortunately I was not able to contact authors about it. BTW don't forget to edit win32.h and set

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

Comment: @ygrek--thanks a lot.  I'll try the patch.  I appreciate the pointer on the win32.h as well.

Comment: @ygrek--that seems to have done the trick but there are other issues--unresolved symbols during linking.  I suspect this is due to the fact that I'm trying to build with VS2010.  But, either way, thanks for the help.